# sampling from a clipped normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy

How do I sample from a normal distribution that is clipped?

I want to sample from `N(0, 1)`. But I want the values to be from `[-1, +1]`. I cannot apply `np.clip` as that would increase the probability of `-1` and `+1`. I can do stochastic clipping, but then there's no guarantee that it'll fall out of the range.

```
#standard
s = np.random.normal(0, 1, [10,10])
s = np.clip(s)

#stochastic
for j in range(10)
    edge1 = np.where(s[j] >= 1.)[0]
    edge2 = np.where(s[j] <= -1)[0]

    if edge1.shape[0] > 0:
        rand_el1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1, edge1.shape[0])) 
        s[j,edge1] = rand_el1
    if edge2.shape[0] > 0:
        rand_el2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1, edge2.shape[0]))                            
        s[j,edge2] = rand_el2
```

Comment: You could iteratively resample the out-of-bounds elements. Your current solution only provides the first iteration. You also don't need a separate test for each outlier.

Comment: `if edge*.shape[0] > 0:` -> `if edge*.size:`

Comment: is there no solution without an iterative fashion

Comment: I can't guarantee absolutely that there isn't, but if I am not mistaken, selecting from a Gaussian distribution is an iterative process in and of itself. Not that that is 100% relevant, but it is a good indication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scipy library implements the truncated normal distribution as [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html).  In your case, you can use `sample = truncnorm.rvs(-1, 1, size=sample_size)`.

For example,

```
In [55]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [56]: from scipy.stats import truncnorm, norm
```

Sample 100000 points from the normal distribution truncated to [-1, 1]:

```
In [57]: sample = truncnorm.rvs(-1, 1, size=100000)
```

Make a histogram, and plot the theoretical PDF curve.  The PDF can be computed with `truncnorm.pdf`, or with a scaled version of `norm.pdf`.

```
In [58]: _ = plt.hist(sample, bins=51, normed=True, facecolor='g', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.4)

In [59]: x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)

In [60]: plt.plot(x, truncnorm.pdf(x, -1, 1), 'k', alpha=0.4, linewidth=5)
Out[60]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11f78c160>]

In [61]: plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x)/(norm.cdf(1) - norm.cdf(-1)), 'k--', linewidth=1)
Out[61]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11f779f60>]
```

Here's the plot:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the simplest (perhaps not most efficient) way to do so is to use basic Rejection sampling. It simply consists in simulating values from a `N(0,1)`, rejecting those that fall out of the wanted bounds and keeping the others until they stack to the wanted number of samples.

```
kept = []
while len(kept) < 1000:
    s = np.random.normal()
    if -1 <= s <= 1:
        kept.append(s)
```

Here I stack things in a basic list ; feel free to use a np.array and replace the length condition with one based on the array's dimensions.

Comment: I had considered this solution, and it is indeed the simplest in terms of logic, but it has the drawback of requiring at least N iterations of a native Python loop, which is much more expensive than vectorizing the same operation.

Comment: I can only agree with you on the advantage of vectorizing the operation, and I tend to find your solution more elegant than mine. I posted it however because I was done writing it down when your post came up, and because it may feel easier to understand for any beginner reaching this page.

Answer (score 1):

Do the stochiastic clipping iteratively until you don't need it any more. This basically means turning your `if`s into a `while`. You can also take this opportunity to simplify the out-of bounds condition into a single check rather than a separate check on each side:

```
s = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 10))
while True:
    out_of_bounds = np.abs(s) > 1
    count = np.count_nonzero(out_of_bounds)
    if count:
        s[out_of_bounds] = np.random.normal(0, 1, count)
    else:
        break
```